# Overwrite index file in /var/www with vcsrepo

Tags: git, apache, puppet, puppet-enterprise

I am trying to make a puppet module which will overwrite the default index.file (which comes with apaceh2) in `/var/www/` with the index file I have in my git repository. I am using the puppet plugin Vcsrepo to clone the repository.

```
 vcsrepo { "/var/www/":
                provider => git,
                source => "git@git.*****/testing.git",
                identity => '/root/.ssh/id_rsa',
                require => Package['git'],
        }
```

I am right now getting this error:

```
Error: /Stage[main]/Web::Repository/Vcsrepo[/var/www/]: Could not evaluate: undefined method `include?' for nil:NilClass
```

I have tried with `force=>"true"`, without managing to solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way of doing this would be to clone the git repository to another location, and then use a `file` resource to make `index.file` either a copy or a symlink to the version in the checkout.

```
vcsrepo { "/tmp/apacherepo":
  provider => git,
  source   => "git@git.*****/testing.git",
  identity => '/root/.ssh/id_rsa',
  require  => Package['git'],
}

file { '/var/www/index.file':
  ensure  => present,
  source  => '/tmp/apacherepo/index.file',
  require => Vcsrepo['/tmp/apacherepo']
}
```

Comment: I am getting this error: Error: /Stage[main]/Webserver::Repository/File[/var/www/index.file]: Could not evaluate: Could not retrieve information from environment production source(s) file:/tmp/apacherepo/index.file

Comment: Is the Vcsrepo working and occurring before the file resource?